# Modify Prediction from randomForest function in R

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, decision-tree

I have a question about the `randomForest` function in R's `randomForest` package.  I have built a random forest to predict an outcome `y`, from a series of predictors, but one of the predictors, call it `x1`, should serve as an absolute lower bound to my prediction, `y`.  Without editing the `randomForest` function itself, is there any way I can tell the `randomForest` to use `x1` as a lower prediction bound?  To make this more clear, I'll provide an example.

Say one one row of my training dataset looks like this:

```
y      x1      x2      x3      x4
=====================================
19.1   24.2    1       19.2     3.33
```

I was hoping there would be a relatively simple way to call `randomForest` and tell the procedure when predicting `y`, never predict anything less than `x1`.  In this case, if the default prediction for `y` (without any constraint) was going be 18.8, I would like to replace this prediction with 24.2.  Is this easily do-able?  I reviewed the R documentation on this and didn't see anything that would allow me to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just apply `x1` as a lower bound to `y` after the prediction is made? (`df$y <- pmax(df$y, df$x1`)

Comment: Your one example training point has y < x1. It seems odd that you would give it this point and expect x1 to be a lower bound.

Comment: @Calumn You, I appreciate the suggestion, but unfortunately, I wanted to make use of the build in mse and other statistics returned from randomForest.  The method you proposed doesn't allow for that.

Comment: @G5W, I'm not sure I understand your concern.  Your question seems to be a reiteration of my entire question.  The problem I'm facing is that randomForest returns larger values than I'd like to allow.  The example I've provided for y is the actual value of y, not y-hat the predicted value.

Comment: You described the point as a training point, i.e. you are telling RF that for this point, y=19.1 is a good value. It would help some if before training you set y = pmin(y, x1)

Comment: I guess I could have been more clear and said y is the actual value in my training dataset.  What you have proposed does not result in predicted values that are guaranteed to be greater than x1.